# How to promote a new social network?

Tags: social-media, website-promotion

I'm developing social network scripts for clients and this question is often asked by them after the script is released.

Beside existing big social networks like `www.facebook.com` (USA), `www.nerofix.com` (Europe) and `www.vkontakte.com` (Russia), how would you promote a new network and where (+ how) to advertise?

Comment: 1. Go to bank/venture capitalist/investor. 2. Get money. 3. Advertise/Cooperate with others.

Comment: Money is not a problem, about advertising: How would you promote? Just with the sentence "Hey a new social network is there."? I think the focus should be to reach, that existing users will invite their friends if they like, but how to tell them the best way?

Comment: Advertising is not hard. You need to advertise your USPs for the target audience seeking that UPC. The actual wording needs to be such, to distinguish your social network from others and how you make life better for your members. Do that, with infinite money and you'll get your target audience faster than anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a social network targets users online, you should build a strong online presence for your new site:

- pitch big online magazines. If you manage to get covered by Mashable
  or Gigaom, you'll get your first users instantly. Search for the 
  submit news form (http://mashable.com/submit/) or contact journalists
  directly via e-mail/Twitter/Google+, etc.
- create some viral content - a video can be a good choice. This should
  be something really catchy and humorous and it should    highlight
  the    features of your network.
- introduce the system of invites - something which is limited at the
  beginning can look much more attractive than when it's    available
  to    everybody.
- be ready to answer the main question - why should I register on one
  more social network and spend even more time online?
- try any kind of online advertising to get maximum online visibility
  (Google AdWords ads and banners, paid placements on    popular blogs,
  etc.)

Whatever you start doing to promote your social network, be sure to give it some time - there's almost no way of getting instant success - unless Mr. Zuckerberg himself announces the launch of it :) 
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, great and respectable answer. If you have the time, you can extend point 4 (why shoudl I register) a bit more for me please, however, already great answer at all.